# Undefined Variable in JSON Object in Node Module

Tags: node.js

I can't figure out why I get an undefined here for 'app':

```
module.exports = {
    application: require('../../app').service,
    request: require('supertest')(this.application),
    startSetup: setup(this.application)
};
```

it throws up at the (this.application) for the request: line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yo can try this:

```
var app = require('../../app').service;

module.exports = {
    application: app,
    request: require('supertest')(app),
    startSetup: setup(app)
};
```

The problems is that `this.application` doesn't exists yet.

You can't use the inside parts of an object that it is not defined (it is defined only after the final `}`).

Here is an example that you can try on your chrome console.

[image]

You can see that you can't use type because it is not defined.

Comment: But Webstorm intellisense resolved the application just fine in terms of being able to click it to see what object it is referring to

Comment: @WeDoTDD that doesn't mean it's valid and will work when ran. In fact, it works because it IS valid, and is doing exactly what it should by giving you undefined. If webstorm gives you anything other than undefined, it is wrong.

Comment: @KevinB is right. I'd edited my question in order to be a little more clear about it and with a live example duplicating your case.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript doesn't know what `this.application` is. The object hasn't been defined yet so you can't use an attribute inside at object definition that's defined in the same object.

Comment: Webstorm resolves it just fine so why is that if you are saying there is no scope yet for this?

Comment: Because webstorm is just parsing your files and trying to suggest what it thinks will work or help you type less. Webstorm is not a JavaScript runtime.